# Как добавить Entry в Messagebox tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, entry

хотел бы спросить, как добавить в Messagebox поле ввода в параметре deatils например, и по нажатию кнопки "ok" записать ввод в переменную в главном окне?

```
def dateset() 
  ㅤ mb.showinfo(title="title",message='Ent er you answer:')
    
...

helpmenu.add_command(label='Установить дату',command=dateset)
```

Comment: Никак. Сделайте свое диалоговое окно через Toplevel и добавьте в него все что нужно. Есть готовые диалоги с полем ввода (модуль [tkinter.simpledialog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.simpledialog)), но они довольно страшно выглядят.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться pyautogui,а точнее командой pyautogui.prompt()

```
    import pyautogui as pg
    value=pg.prompt("Текст в окне","Название окна")
```

После закрытия окна value будет значение  введённое в поле ввода